# How to evaluate the difference between two classes of data which are highly overlapped

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I’m trying to implement a classifier based on a dataset comprising two classes of high dimensional time-series observations (the values of the two classes of observations are highly similar).

I created a SVM binary classifier but the area under ROC curve was only around 60%. Last week, my friend suggested me to try Gaussian Processes (GPs): find hyper-parameters for the GPs by fitting a model to each patient’s time-series vital-sign data and determine if there is difference on values of hyper-parameters between each sample.

However, the corresponding hyper-parameters for each dimension between the two classes are still similar (both mean and variance). Could anyone suggest some better metrics or algorithms suitable to measure the difference between two classes of data?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about programming. Please consider posting it at http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Or [stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com may even be of use as well, as this deals with some signal processing concepts